# What are the pros and cons of using GenericForeignKey vs multitable inheritance vs OneToOneField?

Tags: django, database

**Context**

I am in the process of modeling my data using Django models.
The main model is an `Article`. It holds the actual content.

Then each `Article` must be attached to a group of articles. Those group may be a `Blog`, a `Category` a `Portfolio` or a `Story`. Every `Article` must be attached to one, and exactly one of those. That is, either a blog, a category or a story. Those models have very different fields and features.

I thought of three ways to reach that goal (and a bonus one that really looks wrong).

**Option #1: A generic foreign key**

As in `django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey`. It would look like this:

```
class Category(Model):
    # some fields

class Blog(Model):
    # some fields

class Article(Model):
    group_type = ForeignKey(ContentType)
    group_id = PositiveIntegerField()
    group = GenericForeignKey('group_type', 'group_id')
    # some fields
```

On the database side, that means no relation actually exists between the models, they are enforced by Django.

**Option #2: Multitable inheritance**

Make article groups all inherit from an `ArticleGroup` model. This would look like this:

```
class ArticleGroup(Model):
    group_type = ForeignKey(ContentType)

class Category(ArticleGroup):
    # some fields

class Blog(ArticleGroup):
    # some fields

class Article(Model):
    group = ForeignKey(ArticleGroup)
    # some fields
```

On the database side, this creates an additional table for `ArticleGroup`, then `Category` and `Blog` have an implicit foreign key to that table as their primary key.

Sidenote: *I know there is [a package](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) that automates the bookkeeping of such constructions.*

**Option #3: manual OneToOneFields**

On the database side, it is equivalent to option #2. But in the code, all relations are made explicit:

```
class ArticleGroup(Model):
    group_type = ForeignKey(ContentType)

class Category(Model):
    id = OneToOneField(ArticleGroup, primary_key=True)
    # some fields

class Blog(Model):
    id = OneToOneField(ArticleGroup, primary_key=True)
    # some fields

class Article(Model):
    group = ForeignKey(ArticleGroup)
    # some fields
```

I don't really see what the point of that would be, apart from making explicit what Django's inheritance magic implicitly does.

**Bonus: multicolumn**

It seems pretty dirty so I just add it as a bonus, but it would also be possible to define a nullable ForeignKey to each of `Category`, `Blog`, ... directly on the `Article` model.

**So...**

...I cannot really decide between those. What are the pros and cons of each approach? Are there some best practices? Did I miss a better approach?

If that matters, I'm using Django 1.8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems noone had advice to share on that one.
I eventually chose the multicolumn option, despite having said it looked ugly. It all came down to 3 things:

- Database-based enforceability.
- The way Django ORM works with the different constructs.
- My own needs (namely, collection queries on the group to get the item list, and individual queries on the items to get the group).

**Option #1**

- Cannot be enforced at the database level.
- Could be efficient on queries because the way it is constructed does not fall into usual generic foreign key pitfalls. Those happen when the items are generic, not the collections.
- However, due to how the ORM handles GFK, it is impossible to use a custom manager, which I need because my articles are translated using [django-hvad](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad).

**Option #2**

- Can be enforced at the database level.
- Could be somewhat efficient, but runs into ORM limitations, which is clearly not built around this use. Unless I use `extra()` or custom queries alot, but at some point there is no reason to use an ORM anymore.

**Option #3**

- Would actually be a bit better than #2, as making things explicit allows easier query optimisation while using the ORM.

**Multicolumn**

- Turns out not being so bad. It can be enforced at the database level (FK constraints plus a manual CHECK to ensure only one of the columns is non-null).
- Easy and efficient. A single intuitive query does the job: `select_related('category', 'blog', ...)`.
- Though it does have the issue of being harder to extend (any new type will require altering the `Article`'s table as well) and limiting the possible number of types, I'm unlikely to run into those.

Hope it helps anyone with the same dilemma, and still interested in hearing other opinions.

Comment: I agree - the multi-column option is the best as long as you anticipate having only a limited number of classes that it might be related to. For this use case, GFK is evil IMO, because it whacks a hole in your database integrity, and makes queries outside of Django especially hard.