# Make a ForiegnKey to an unknown model in django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I'll illustrate by example

I have

```
class Stone(models.Model):
    # name, color, whatever

class Member(models.Model):
    # whatever

class Image(models.Model):
    stone = models.ForiegnKey(Stone, on_delete=...) # this should have the model that needs images
    image = models.ImageField()
```

I'm using a foriegnKey to the Image model to make multiple images, But This forces me to create an Image model for each Model, In my example, Stone can has multiple images right? I want Member and all my models that need images to use the same class, I want to make only one images table.

I've been searching for a while but I don't think I know what should be the search text, I read about `ContentType` but I don't think I understand what it does and I don't even know if it's the what I'm asking for.

Edit 1: I actually thought of creating 2 nullable `ForiegnKeys` but this seems like a work around and not a solution.

Comment: If there are limited number of models that need images, you can try nullable FK to them or add a type field. Also have a look at django-polymorphic

Comment: This SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562039/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-genericforeignkey-vs-multitable-inheritance) shows a few options how such a problem might be tackled.

Comment: @Chris Well, I've thought of creating 2 nullable ForiegnKeys but this seems like a work-around and not a solution

Comment: @Adithya Thanks, I'll see if this is possible without any external libs, I'll use that when I give up upon the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ContentType` is what I was looking for, quoted from disqus developer, David Cramer [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-ways-to-improve-Django-performance)

> Generic relations are fine. They are not slow, just more difficult to manage in your code base.

I guess this is answer, I'd like to note that as @Adithya said, `django-polymorphic` can help too as I've tried this and it seems like the easiet solution, Adding the OOP concept *Polymorphism* to the django models system.